# Isomorphisms between quotients of formal power series rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, power-series, formal-power-series

So far I am not really used to see isomorphisms between quotients of formal power series rings.

So let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $R:=k[[x,y]]$ be the ring of formal power series in two variables. Furthermore let $f_+:=y^{(n+1)/2}+ix$ and $f_-:=y^{(n+1)/2}-ix$ where $i:=\sqrt{1}$.

How can I see isomorphisms like this one (which I know must be true):
$$ 
k[[x,y]]/(f_+,f_-)\simeq k[[y]]/(y^{(n+1)/2)}) 
$$

Comment: Do you see that $(y^{(n+1)/2} +ix, y^{(n+1)/2} -ix)=((y^{(n+1)/2}, x)$?

Comment: @Krish Let $I:=(y^{(n+1)/2}+ix,y^{(n+1)/2}-ix)$. $\subseteq$: is clear. The other inclusion: $y^{(n+1)/2}+ix-y^{(n+1)/2}+ix=ix+ix=2ix\in I$. Can I say "2"? $\Rightarrow ix\in I \Rightarrow y^{(n+1)/2}\in I$ and $-i\cdot (ix)=x \in I$. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This works fine as long as Char$(k) \neq 2.$ In that case $2$ is a unit, so you can cancel it out. I asume that Char$(k)\neq 2.$ Otherwise how you are defining $\sqrt{-1}$? In Char $2$, $x^2+1$ is reducible, $x^2+1=(x+1)^2$.

Comment: @Krish I looked into the assumptions of the text I am reading. Indeed $Char(k)=0$ and $n$ is odd btw. Another question: If $f=f_+ f_-$, so $f=y^n+x^2$. and let's say $S:=R/(f)$. Is it true, that $S/(f_-)\simeq R/(f_-)$, since $f\in (f_-)$? And furthermore is it true that $S/(f_-)\simeq S(f_+)$?